# pip install failing with NewConnectionError on debian

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I often do `pip install <package-name>` on my Google Compute Engine (Debian) within the virtual environment but today I am just getting the new connection error for *any package* that I try to install:

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
    after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f42a65bdf60>: 
    Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': 
    /packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919d9c0c085fd2b3775fd3eca826012bef76d8c/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I know there are other related posts that suggest specifying a proxy but I have been `pip install` ing many times in the past on the same machine but somehow its just returning the above error today. Doesn't really look like a proxy issue. What could have changed?

`pip` version is `10.0.1` and the machine obviously has live internet connection (its our prod server on Google Compute Engine). I can successfully ping websites from the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to open `port 443` for outgoing traffic (to specific IP(s)) on Google Compute Engine instance since pip3 runs over HTTPS.

Refer to [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#example_3_allow_egress_tcp_connections_to_port_443_of_an_external_host) for detailed instructions on how to do it (using command line or the GUI). Get the IP of `files.pythonhosted.org` to set the destination IP.

(This [helpful comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/899790/pip-cant-connect-to-anything-on-aws#comment1163866_899790) points out the same issue with using `pip3` on an AWS EC2 instance)